# Listagem de Posts populares contando os comentários do facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

Estou tentando fazer uma lista de 5 itens das postagens mais comentadas do meu blog, mas com os comentários do facebook.

Eu substitui todo o conteúdo do arquivo "comments.php" do meu WP (tema twenty fifteen) por este aqui:

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=779264268806634&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div> </div>
```

e para mostrar o número de comentários de cada post eu utilizo este:

```
<fb:comments-count href=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>></fb:comments-count>
```

Eu tentei utilizar a resposta desta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919791/wordpress-show-popular-posts-based-on-facebook-comments), e ficou deste modo:

Adicionei esta função no **functions.php**:

```
if (!function_exists('fb_comment_count')) { function fb_comment_count() { global $post; $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

    $query = "SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '{$url}'";
    $responseText = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q='.$query);
    $responseJson = json_decode($responseText);

    $commentCount = $responseJson->data->comment_count;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'facebook_comments_count', $commentCount);

    return;
}
}
```

e no arquivo onde eu quero que apareça a **listagem** eu coloquei:

```
  <ul>
    <?php
      $loopMostCommented = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&meta_key=facebook_comments_count&orderby=meta_value&order=DESC');
        while ($loopMostCommented->have_posts()) : $loopMostCommented->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
      <a class="transition-2s" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php url() ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
        <span class="reclink"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
```

Infelizmente nada aparece dentro da tag "**< li >**". Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço muito!

**EDIÇÃO: VAR_DUMP($loopMostCommented)**

> object(WP_Query)#3605 (46) { ["query_vars"]=> array(62) {
>   ["posts_per_page"]=> int(5) ["meta_key"]=> string(23)
>   "facebook_comments_count" ["orderby"]=> string(10) "meta_value"
>   ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0)
>   ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0)
>   ["comments_popup"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0)
>   { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=>
>   bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(false)
>   ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=>
>   bool(true) ["post_type"]=> string(0) "" ["nopaging"]=> bool(false)
>   ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false)
>   } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#3572 (6) { ["queries"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND"
>   ["table_aliases:protected"]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["primary_table"]=> string(8) "wp_posts"
>   ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" } ["meta_query"]=>
>   object(WP_Meta_Query)#3573 (7) { ["queries"]=> array(2) { [0]=>
>   array(1) { ["key"]=> string(23) "facebook_comments_count" }
>   ["relation"]=> string(2) "OR" } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND"
>   ["meta_table"]=> string(11) "wp_postmeta" ["meta_id_column"]=>
>   string(7) "post_id" ["primary_table"]=> string(8) "wp_posts"
>   ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" ["table_aliases:protected"]=>
>   array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "wp_postmeta" } } ["date_query"]=>
>   bool(false) ["post_count"]=> int(0) ["current_post"]=> int(-1)
>   ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0)
>   ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0)
>   ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0)
>   ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=>
>   bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=>
>   bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=>
>   bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_home"]=> bool(true) ["is_404"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_comments_popup"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false)
>   ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false)
>   ["query_vars_hash:private"]=> string(32)
>   "a186c4864cb9d6fa90fd5b23b6fc8fa2" ["query_vars_changed:private"]=>
>   bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false)
>   ["stopwords:private"]=> NULL ["query"]=> array(4) {
>   ["posts_per_page"]=> string(1) "5" ["meta_key"]=> string(23)
>   "facebook_comments_count" ["orderby"]=> string(10) "meta_value"
>   ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" } ["request"]=> string(365) "SELECT
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
>   ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND
>   wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR
>   wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key =
>   'facebook_comments_count' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY
>   wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 5" ["posts"]=> array(0) { } }

Obs.: eu não ser ler isso ainda =/

Comment: se você fizer um var_dump do $loopMostCommented qual é o resultado?

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb Eu fiz o que você sugeriu e o resultado eu postei acima. Espero que possas me ajudar e me desculpe pela demora.

Comment: O seu wp_query não retornou nenhum post. Provavelmente o erro está na criação do campo facebook_comments_count porque você está usando FQL que não funciona para apps novos. Você vai ter que usar a Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2

Comment: Eu não sei como se usa isso, pode me ajudar? @RicardoBRGWeb

Comment: Oi Luna, estou sem tempo pra estudar a graph api agora, mas assim que conseguir eu coloco a resposta aqui...