# Como mostrar uma listagem de todos os posts em qualquer página

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou querendo fazer uma lista para pegar as postagens mais comentadas, mas o meu problema é que eu não consigo chamar a listagem certa sempre, eis o código:

```
        <ul>
        <?php 
            global $query_string;
            query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=-1, post_status=publish');

            if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post();

            $post_name = get_the_title();
            $post_url  = get_permalink();
        ?>
            <li>
                <a class="transition-2s" title="<?php $post_name; ?>" href="<?php $post_url; ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
                    <span class="reclink"><?php echo $post_name; ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php 
            endwhile; 
            endif;
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Na página inicial funciona muito bem, mas em uma página específica, como a de uma postagem por exemplo, esse código só faz a listagem de um único item, que é a do post em questão.

Quero lançar esse código no rodapé, para que sempre apareça, independente da página que o leitor esteja.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 3):

Tem alguns problemas aqui, no título você diz que quer listar todos, mas na descrição você esta dizendo que quer listar o mais comentários...

Enfim, de qualquer forma isso não vai funcionar porque você esta pegando o `$query_string` que muda de uma página para outra.

Além que não se deve utilizar [`query_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), basta ler na documentação que o correto é usar `pre_get_posts` para alterar os loops que já existem e os adicionais devem ser feitos com [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Para listar todos você poderia utilizar:

```php
<ul>
    <?php 
        $all_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'nopaging' => true, // deve ser usado no lugar de posts_per_page -1
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ) );

        if ( $all_posts_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $all_posts_query->have_posts() ) :
                $all_posts_query->the_post();
            ?>

            <li>
                <a class="transition-2s" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
                    <span class="reclink"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

É bem simples agora também mudar isso para pegar **as postagens mais comentadas**, pois basta ordenar pelo número de comentários.

```php
<ul>
    <?php 
        $all_posts_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'nopaging' => true, // deve ser usado no lugar de posts_per_page -1
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'comment_count', // Ordena pelos mais comentados
            'order' => 'DESC' // Começa pelos números maiores, exemplo 10, 9, 8...
        ) );

        if ( $all_posts_query->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $all_posts_query->have_posts() ) :
                $all_posts_query->the_post();
            ?>

            <li>
                <a class="transition-2s" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"> 
                    <span class="reclink"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Bom é isso, agora você consegue fazer as duas consultas.

Entretanto não recomendo sempre carregar todos os posts assim de uma vez, pois se você tiver muitos posts isso vai causar problemas de desempenho.
No caso dos mais comentados eu recomendo usar `posts_per_page` de `10` ou algo assim.

Comment: Entendo, obrigada pela ajuda! Você tem razão, vou ter graves problemas de desempenho. Eu tava tentando fazer uma gambiarra, mas vai acabar sendo pior. A minha intenção é só a dos mais comentados, mas eu utilizo os comentários do facebook como eu perguntei [nesse post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52461/listagem-de-posts-populares-contando-os-coment%C3%A1rios-do-facebook?noredirect=1#comment110681_52461) e me disseram que eu teria que usar o API do facebook, mas como não sei, estava tentando contornar, mas parece que é mais ruim do que bom... De qualquer forma, eu agradeço muito!